# posting requests with selenium data

Tags: python, selenium

How can I use post requests with Selenium's driver saved data?

```
currency = {
  "type": "to-bits",
  "amount": "1",
}
```

I want to post this request using the account I'm logged in to the selenium browser (by this I mean websites account), Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry, let me edit it

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Sure, what do you need to know?

Comment: I assume this is the JSON(payload) which you want to send as part of some request, right?

Comment: Is that REST API? or where do you want to post this data? To broswer?